# simplecart javascript total cost tax calculating

Tags: simplecart

I use simplecart-js 2.2.2 script and i have a problem that my programming knowledge can't solve it.

My code right now calculate tax for a single item without shipping price.
So if an item cost: 3$ & shipping cost 2$ and the tax is 4%, gives me = 5.12$
which is not right, the right price is = 5.20$

I want tax calculation for the cart (all items & shipping cost).

Is there any solution to update the script just for the tax calculation.
I can't change the script with version 3 because i am using a specific template in blogger that is designed for this version.

I have already update the code with the paypal tax fix and i am asking if there is a way to fix the tax calculation in this version.

This is my script:
http://pastebin.com/0SakbdWV

Please help me with this, i am searching for days.

Thank you very much.